# How to mitigate Apache Log4j Deserialization RCE (CVE-2019-17571)

Tags: java, log4j

I have upgraded my log4j-core dependency to 2.15.0 in order to prevent any potential Log4Shell attack. That being said I could not upgrade slf4j-log4j12's indirect log4j dependency from 1.2.17 since the latest stable version of slf4j-log4j12 is still dependent on log4j 1.2.17. This still leaves my webapp vulnerable to [CVE-2019-17571](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-17571/) if I am not mistaken. So reading about possible mitigation strategies I came across this [article](https://nsfocusglobal.com/apache-log4j-deserialization-remote-code-execution-cve-2019-17571-vulnerability-threat-alert/) which recommends to :

> prevent the socket port enabled by the SocketServer class in Log4j
> from being opened to the public network

Could anyone please explain to me how can this be achieved and whether would this workaround be sufficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only servers that receive messages from other servers are vulnerable to `CVE-2019-17571`. Basically the only way to trigger the vulnerability is to run:

```
java -jar log4j.jar org.apache.log4j.net.SocketServer <port> <config.properties> <log/directory>
```

or doing the equivalent in code. Therefore most Log4j 1.2 users are not vulnerable.

In your case, however, you just need to replace the [`slf4j-log4j12`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12) binding with its Log4j 2.x equivalent ([`log4j-slf4j-impl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl)) and you can remove Log4j 1.2 altogether.

**Edit**: Nevertheless, if you want to be certain no one will use the library as above, you can remove the class. Considering also [`CVE-2021-4104`](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-4104) this amount to:

```
zip -d log4j.jar org/apache/log4j/net/SocketServer.class
zip -d log4j.jar org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.class
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the only way? Do you have any ref that explains the attack more in depth? thx

Comment: @robob: the attach is a simple [deserialization attack](https://www.baeldung.com/java-deserialization-vulnerabilities). Basically the `SocketServer` deserializes everything it receives from everyone on the network. There are no references to `SocketServer` in the remaining Log4j classes, so it is not used unless you call it explicitly.