# How to Override log4j with log4j2 version to resolve "SocketServer class vulnerable to deserialization" for apache-core_2.12 version

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, sparkcore

How to Override log4j version 1.2.17 with log4j-core 2.16.0 version to resolve "SocketServer class vulnerable to deserialization" for spark-core_2.12 binaries.

I tried to exclude log4j - 1.2.17 from spark-core_2.12, but the build is failing with below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter
    at com.optum.iqs.runtime.counters.CountersFactoryTest.setup(CountersFactoryTest.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.spi.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 19 more

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.optum.iqs.runtime.counters.CountersFactoryTest.tearDown(CountersFactoryTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.invokeMethod(RunAfters.java:46)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

**My CountersFactoryTest.java class content is**

```
    package com.optum.iqs.runtime.counters;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
    import org.junit.AfterClass;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.Test;
    
    public class CountersFactoryTest {
        public static SparkSession sparkSession;
    
        @BeforeClass
        public static void setup() throws IOException {
            sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("JunitSession").master("local").getOrCreate();
            CountersFactory.initialize(sparkSession.sparkContext());
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testIqsLongCounter() {
            Dataset<String> input = sparkSession.read().textFile("src/test/resources/input.txt").as(Encoders.STRING());
            Dataset<String> output = input.map(new SampleMapFunction(), Encoders.STRING());
            output.show();
            Long counter = CountersFactory.getCounters().get("input records").value();
            Assert.assertEquals(3L, counter.longValue());
        }
        
        @Test
        public void testIqsOutputRecordCounter() {
            Dataset<String> input = sparkSession.read().textFile("src/test/resources/input.txt").as(Encoders.STRING());
            Dataset<String> output = input.map(new SampleMapFunctionOutputCounter(), Encoders.STRING());
            output.show();
            Map<String, Long> counter = CountersFactory.getOutputCounters().get("output records").value();
            Assert.assertEquals(3L, counter.get("key").longValue());
        }
    
        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDown() {
            sparkSession.stop();
        }
    }
```

reference to excluding log4j from spark core dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Is spark-core going to upgrade log4j dependency to latest version ?

[CVE-2019-17571](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-17571/)

Comment: I tried to add Filter.java class within my code so that it doesn't look for it from log4j dependency, still I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 2):

[**Remark**: [`CVE-2019-1751`](https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2019-17571) is almost impossible to trigger, unless you are running the `SocketServer` explicitly (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70345869/11748454)). On the other hand Log4j 1.2.17 also suffers from [`CVE-2021-4104`](https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2021-4104), which might be easier to exploit.]

Since Log4j 2.x is not backward compatible with Log4j 1.2 upgrading is not as simple as replacing one library with the other. You need to **replace** the `log4j` dependency with the bridge between Log4j 1.2 and Log4j 2.x API (`log4j-1.2-api`):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This should solve the `ClassNotFoundException`, but if you want to actually save the logs somewhere, you need to install a backend for the Log4j 2.x API.  [`log4j-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.16.0) is the standard one.